# PHP: how to do foreach and start from sixth element of collection?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

is it possible to start a foreach loop from specific element [sixth element]?

im using this code:

```
    <?php
    $num=1;
    foreach($temp_row as $key => $value) {

        echo $num;

        $num++;
    }
    ?>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use for example [array_slice()](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$num = 5; //it will start from sixth element

foreach(array_slice($temp_row, $num) as $key => $value) {

     echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Not directly with a `foreach()`. The clue is in the `each` part of the name. It loops through *all* elements.

So how can we achieve it?

You could always just have an `if()` clause inside the loop that checks the key value before doing the rest of the work.

But if that's not workable for you, for whatever reason, I'd suggest using a [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) to achieve this.

The `FilterIterator` is a standard PHP class which you can extend to create your own filters. The iterator can then be looped using a standard `foreach()` loop, picking up only the records that are accepted by the filter.

There are some examples on the manual page linked above that will help, but here's a quick example I've thrown together for you:

```
class SkipTopFilter extends FilterIterator {
    private $filterNum = 0;
    public function __construct(array $array, $filter) {
        parent::__construct(new ArrayIterator($array));
        $this->filterNum = $filter;
    }
    public function accept() {
        return ($this->getInnerIterator()->key() >= $this->filterNum);
    }
}

$myArray = array(13,6,8,3,22,88,12,656,78,188,99);
foreach(new SkipTopFilter($myArray, 6) as $key=>$value) {
    //loop through all records except top six.
    print "rec: $key => $value<br />";
}
```

Tested; outputs:

```
rec: 6 => 12
rec: 7 => 656
rec: 8 => 78
rec: 9 => 188
rec: 10 => 99
```

Answer (score 2):

you could skip if counter is not 6th element...

```
<?php
$num=0;
foreach($temp_row as $key => $value) {
    if( ++$num < 6 )
    {
        continue;
    }
    echo $num;
}
?>
```

Comment: not a brilliant solution... what if there are thousands and thousands of items to be skipped?

Comment: yep - not best if you are skipping many more items but small sets its not gonna be a pain. always trade-off with this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Or with a for loop

```
$num = 1;
for($i=5; $i<= count($temp_row), $i++) {
   echo $num;
   $num++;
}
```

Comment: it would be better to calculate the count($temp_row) outside of the for loop

Comment: it can be inside, `for($i=5, $cnt = count($temp_row); $i<= $cnt, ++$i)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
$new_temp_row = array_slice($temp_row, 5);

foreach($new_temp_row as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($temp_row as $key => $value) {
    if (($num = $i++) < 6) continue;
    // Do something
}
```

Or

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) next($temp_row);
while(list($key, $value) = each($temp_row)) {
    // Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a for look instead of a for each. You can then access both the key and value that are at i position inside your loop.

```
<?php
$num = 1;
$keys = array_keys( $temp_row );
for( $i = 5; $i < count( $temp_row ); $i++ ) {
            $key = $keys[$i];
            $val = $temp_row[$i];
    echo $i;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create new array with needed data part of origin array and work with it:

```
$process = array_slice ($temp_row, 5);
foreach($process as $key => $value) {

    //TODO Your logic
}
```

Or you may skipp first siel elments:

```
<?php
$num=1;
foreach($temp_row as $key => $value) {
    if ($num < 6) {
         $num++;
         continue;
    }
    //TODO Your logic
}
?>
```

Comment: just... just delete your second suggestion. what if he had to skip 100000 elements?